# How do Vectors and Matrices work into computer graphics, such as Matrix Rotations?

Tags: c#, xna, drawing, shapes, vector-graphics

I have been trying to wrap my head around how my Linear and Vector Algerbra knowledge fits in with Computer Graphics. Particulary in the language C#

The knowledge I mean is:
Points
Vectors
Matrices
Matrix multiplaction - Rotations, Skews, etc..

Heres my goal: Create a simple box, and apply a rotation, translation, and skew to it via matrix multiplication. Afterwards, start messing around with the camera. I wish to do this all myself, only using the functions that actually take in the data and draw it. I wish to create all the logical stuff inbetween.

Heres what i've got so far:
My custom Vector3 class, which holds 
-an X, Y, and Z variable (floats)
-Several static matrices (as 2x2 2d float arrays?) that hold ZERO and TRANSLATION matrices (for 2x2 and 3x3)
-Methods
 1. Rotate(float inAngle) - Creates a rotation matrix and multiplies the xyz by it.
 2. Translate(inx,iny,inz) - Adds the ins to the member variables
 3. etc...

When complete, i translate the vector back into a C# Vector3 class and pass it to a drawing class, such as DrawPrimitiveShapes which would draw Lines.

The box class is like this:
4 Vector3's, UpperLeftX, UpperRightX, LowerLeftX, LowerRightX

a Draw class which uses the 4 points to then render lines to each one

My confusion comes at this:

How do I rotate this box? Am I on the right track by using 4 vector3's for the box?
Do I just rotate all four vector3's by the angle and be done with it? How does a texture get rotated if it's got all this texture data in the middle?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with linear algebra and whatever you're trying to do, but it sounds like you're operating on a much lower level than XNA requires (I assume you're using XNA because you tagged it as such?).  XNA has a pre-built Matrix class with tons of useful static methods to create a matrix to transform your object however you please.  You can use Vector3.Transform to move your vertices according to the matrix you build.  There are plenty of tutorials on using matrices for 3d object manipulation.  Sorry if I misunderstand what you intend to do here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment A-Type. You seem to get what i'm trying to do just fine. Any idea what better language I can use to easily draw Vectors and Lines to a screen? I was hoping to keep it 2D, but I noticed most people used Vector3's even for 2D uses, leaving the z value at 0.

Comment: XNA certainly kind of sucks at drawing simple vectors and lines, honestly.  It's geared toward drawing full model meshes.  I have seen physics demonstrations from my professor which feature some vector drawing in a coordinate plane using Python.  See if this helps you though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196414%28v=xnagamestudio.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks again. I've been going off this knowledge and the post by Steve. I've currently created my own Vector3 class (Which is a bit sily, since it just converts back to a Vector3 when done with translations) and a Cube class that creates the 8 vertices based off a Position, Length, Width, and Height. I use the Basic Effects to just shove in an array of 36 VertexPositionNormalTexture, and then draw it. This is real hacky, but it works for now and is getting the job done. If I can post the code somewhere to help others I will.

Answer (score 0):

The way I learned is by using the upper level built in Xna methods and using 'Reflector' to see inside those methods to see how they work.

To rotate the box, each of the four vertices needs to be transformed from where they were to: a number of degrees about a particular axis.

In Xna 2d the axis is always the Z axis and that axis **always** runs through the worlds origin, the top left corner of the screen in xna.

So to rotate your four rectangle vertices in xna, you would do something like this:

```
foreach(Vector2 vert in vertices)
{
   vert = Vector2.Transform(vert, Matrix.CreateRotationZ(someRadians));
}
```

This gets the vertices to rotate (orbit) the top left corner of the screen.

In order to have the box rotate in place, you would first move the box to the top left corner of the screen , rotate it a bit, then move it back. All this happens in a single frame so all the user sees is the rectangle rotating in place. There are many ways to do that in code but here is my favorite:

```
// assumes you know the center of the rectangle's x & y as a Vector2 'center'    
foreach(Vector2 vert in vertices)
    {
       vert = Vector2.Transform(vert - center, Matrix.CreateRotationZ(someRadians)) + center;
    }
```

Now if you were to reflect the "Matrix.CreateRotationZ" method, or the "Vector2.Transform" method, you would see the lines of code MS used to make that work. By working through them, you can learn the math behind more efficiently without so much trial and error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the in depth reply, Steve. I think I just about understand how im going to pull this off. My last question for you: What class/methods are you using to display the box graphically? (Spritebatch? DrawPrimitiveLines?)

Comment: I hardly ever work in 2d, I'm not sure which would be better. Might make a good question for this forum though.